# Swift UI design issues

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, design-patterns

I have a list with json data filled in `GetListView()` view. now i am showing this list in SecondView. here i want to show the GetListView from white view bottom to screen bottom to 20. but i can able to give only height: 500 for the  GetListView.. i want it should be bottom to 20 of the screen

**How to show list upto bottom to 20 in `SecondView`**

and please guide me if i used any unnecessary code

**GetListView code:** here how to remove the line b/w cells and the topspace

```
struct GetListView: View {

@StateObject var getData = GetServiceViewModel()

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(){
        
        Text("Friends List")
        List(getData.dataRes?.data ?? [], id: \.id ){ item in
            
            ZStack (){
                Color.yellow
                
                HStack(alignment: .top){
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.avatar), content: { image in
                        image.resizable()
                    }, placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                        Text("Load..")
                    })
                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(height: 70)
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                        Text(item.firstName)
                        Text(item.email)
                        Text("description shjfgds fgds gf dsgf gds fyg dsygf ydsg fgyds gf ydsg fgyds gf dsy fgyds fgyd s...")
                            .padding(.bottom, 15)
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 15){
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("12/3/2024")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                            Text("New")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                        }
                        
                        Button("TestButton") {
                            print("index of list \(item)")
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 5, bottom: 5 , trailing: 10))
                    Spacer()
                }
                
            }
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
            
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            
            .contentShape(Rectangle())  tappable
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView(seltData: item)) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                    .opacity(0)
            )
        }
        .task{
            getData.postAndGetGenericCall(completion: {
                print("Data loaded: \(String(describing: getData.dataRes?.data))")
            })
        }
        .background(Color.red)
    }
    
}
}
```

**SecondView code:**

```
struct SecondView: View {

var body: some View {
    ZStack {

        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        HStack(alignment: .top) {
                            Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .modifier(ImageModifier(width: 70, height: 79))
                                .padding(.top, 10)

                            Rectangle()
                                .background(.red)
                                .frame(width: 5)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)

                    VStack(spacing: 10) {

                        Group {

                            Text("Jhon Thomas")

                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))
                                .font(.system(size: 20))

                            RowItem(text: "000000000", icon: "phone.fill")

                            RowItem(text: "Singer", icon: "bag.fill")
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

                        HStack {
                            RowItem(text: "Jhon Thomas", icon: "location.fill")

                            Spacer()

                            RowItem(text: "Jhon Thomas", icon: "map.fill")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(height: 200)
                .background(.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

                GetListView()
                    .frame(height: 500)
            }
            .padding()

        }
    }
    .background(.red)
}
```

**How to show list upto bottom to 20 in `SecondView`** please guide

o/p: Swift Ui is weird :( it taking its own spaces and padding not able to give required constraints. i can able to catch the coding but when it comes to UI part it is so difficult for me to understand.

[image]

**EDIT:**

If i remove two height frames then got something like this list is not showing.. thats the issue

[image]

Comment: This may be happening because you are giving everything a fixed height, so it is not using the height that would be available. Try removing `.frame(height: 500)` from `GetListView`

Answer (score 0):

As Benzy said, remove your `.frame` fixed heights, you need to accomodate for any screensize or device!

Since you asked about other unnecessary code: when you use async/await in SwiftUI you don't need the old Combine `@StateObject` anymore, so it becomes just:

```
@State var data: [Data] = []
@Environment(\.service) var service

.task {
    data = await service.getData()
}
```

`Service` should a struct that contains your async func for fetching data. The reason it's an [`EnvironmentKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentkey) is so it can be swapped for Previews. Apple use this pattern for their [`authorizationController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/authorizationcontroller). You can also just init the `Service` struct before you use it, the main thing is the async func you call should not be defined inside anything `@MainActor` like `View` so it can run on a background thread. If you do decide to quickly declare it in `View` you can mark it as `nonisolated` to get the same background behaviour but then also be careful to not update any `@State` from within that one.

Since `.task` runs on every appear you might want to check if you already have data from last time before you it again. Also if you want to re-run if the View is init with a different param like postID or a selection changes, use `.task(id: postID)`.